# Oracle start database with incorrect password

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

I have a question regarding starting oracle database with in correct sys password.

I have provided incorrect password for sys user and I am still able to start database and execute statements. So wondering whether I have missed something while installation or this is how it is?

Any insight into this is highly appreciable, Below is the result of start database.

```
sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Nov 15 16:50:39 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys/d as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  422670336 bytes
Fixed Size                  1336960 bytes
Variable Size             285215104 bytes
Database Buffers          130023424 bytes
Redo Buffers                6094848 bytes
Database mounted.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your OS user is from a DBA group, you can [connect `AS SYSDBA` with OS authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba006.htm#i1006677):

> Two special operating system groups control database administrator
>   connections when using operating system authentication. These groups
>   are generically referred to as OSDBA and OSOPER. The groups are
>   created and assigned specific names as part of the database
>   installation process. [..]
>
> Membership in the OSDBA or OSOPER group affects your connection to the
>   database in the following ways:
>
> - If you are a member of the OSDBA group and you specify AS SYSDBA when
>     you connect to the database, then you connect to the database with the
>     SYSDBA system privilege.
> - If you are a member of the OSOPER group and you specify AS SYSOPER
>     when you connect to the database, then you connect to the database
>     with the SYSOPER system privilege.

You can then use `CONNECT / AS SYSDBA` or even `CONNECT FOO/ANYTHING AS SYSDBA`, the DB will ignore the user/password.

Comment: Great +one. Fantastic answer and very well explained. Thanks